# Next js routing triggers useEffect

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to fetch data inside useEffect using axios but it fetches the data everytime I change the page. Is there a way to not trigger useEffect when changing the page? I tried to use shawllow push but it didn't work. I can't fetch on server side because I use next/router inside axios interceptor.

```
   import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
   const router = useRouter();
   router.push('/', '/', { shallow: true })
```

With the above code, it will trigger useEffect when switching routes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch.get('/endpoint').then(response => {
     // do stuff
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet which does that effect what you explained? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you have something in useEffect that you only want to run once, add an empty array as the dependency array.

Example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      // your axios fetch here
  }, []);
```

Empty array as the dependencies means the effect is run once. If you don't specify the dependencies, the effect will run after every render.

Comment: I have the empty array, forgot to add it inside the snippet.

Comment: Ok, then I'm sorry but I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch.get('/endpoint').then(response => {
     // do stuff
    });
}, []); // the empty array will call useEffect only for first time while loading the component
```

Refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects See **Notes**

Comment: I have the empty array, somehow next routing triggers the rerender of the component and I don't understand why.

Comment: useEffect with empty array will always be called when there is new instance of same component is being rendered (say same component at different location).. Also, if your path for this (referred) component falls into the route then the component will get created again.. check if your component is not part of new route you are pushing..

Answer (score 0):

Shallow-routing only works for same page. See [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats).
If you stick to shallow-routing, you have to aggregate the pages into one page with [dynamic-routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes).

So I think it'd be better to use some cache strategy within useEffect.